# Cairolatex vs epslatex terminal within Latex, implementing PDF plots

Tags: pdf, eps, gnuplot, terminal-output, epslatex

So I've tried to move away from using **eps** within my LaTeX documents and found that the cairolatex terminal in gnuplot has a **pdf** output option that has the advantage of being portable and hence more universal.

My problem is that comparing the output between epslatex and cairolatex terminals this is what happens:
[[image] Both graphs are in a LaTeX file using the geometry package, letterpaper and 1.25 in left and right margins, so that the output size of the graphs is exactly the space that’s left.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3ulC.png)

The code for both graphs is the same, I just uncomment the respective line:

```
data='somedata.dat'

#set ter cairolatex pdf size 6in,7cm
#set o 'cairolatex.tex'
set ter epslatex size 6in,7cm
set o 'epslatex.tex'

set st l 12 lw 2 lc rgb '#728cc1'
set st l 13 lw 2 lc rgb '#e09a34'
set st l 14 lw 2 lc rgb '#90af3c'
set st l 15 lw 2 lc rgb '#e9633d'
set st l 16 lw 2 lc rgb '#8779b1'

set xlab '$\lambda$ (\si{\nm})'
set xtics nomirror; set mxtics 2
set format x '\num{%.1f}'
unset ytics
set border 1
set k a columnheader rm c Left rev

plot for [i=2:6] data u 1:i w l ls 10+i
```

I just want to know if there's a way to have the look of epslatex with the advantage of the pdf output file.

Just for completeness sake here are the first few lines of the data:

```
λ   "T$_{\\mathrm{total}}$" "Filter"    "Filter derivative" "Cavity"    "Gain"
778 0.00489883081825735 0.013448657004757985    0.4748955037766079  0.6476152743632694  0.8743110134269316
778.0002    0.005230472593185875    0.013408366782331165    0.4747429566483844  0.6480147977992771  0.8743232536919348
778.0004    0.0055822116730117515   0.013367838429160814    0.4745978403471201  0.6484159697731217  0.8743354937785731
778.0006    0.005945663981273803    0.013327083834570064    0.4744601548728151  0.6488187901857326  0.8743477336868205
778.0008    0.00630837242242909 0.013286114887835354    0.47432990022532545 0.6492232589285974  0.8743599734166785
778.001 0.006653579409385988    0.013244943478372979    0.47420707640494736 0.6496293758814057  0.8743722129681208
778.0012    0.0069608530274803465   0.013203581495412488    0.4740916834114015  0.6500371409133195  0.8743844523411496
778.0014    0.00720791178803824 0.01316204082837107 0.47398372124495036 0.6504465538807858  0.874396691535738
778.0016    0.007373684237992445    0.013120333366524939    0.4738831899054584  0.6508576146296284  0.8744089305518876
778.0018    0.007442086238286481    0.013078470999197225    0.4737900893929257  0.6512703229930534  0.8744211693895729
778.002 0.007405437370904537    0.013036465615711064    0.4737044197073523  0.6516846787929345  0.874433408048788
778.0022    0.007266274987991157    0.012994329105389585    0.47362618084873803 0.6521006818388363  0.8744456465295277
778.0024    0.007036820953469591    0.012952073357555922    0.47355537281708304 0.6525183319282747  0.8744578848317659
778.0026    0.00673630949032606 0.012909710261484986    0.47349199561231947 0.6529376288461435  0.8744701229555041
778.0028    0.006387212137321582    0.012867251706596245    0.4734360492345914  0.6533585723643429  0.8744823609007158
778.003 0.0060116198761865774   0.01282470958211632 0.47338753368377173 0.6537811622426727  0.8744945986674035
778.0032    0.005628662711973822    0.012782095777465082    0.4733464489599706  0.654205398227622   0.8745068362555402
778.0034    0.0052532341320218065   0.012739422181917346    0.4733127950631287  0.6546312800534826  0.8745190736651278
778.0036    0.004895811719317167    0.012696700684796242    0.47328657199324603 0.6550588074400601  0.8745313108961402
778.0038    0.004562966552118798    0.012653943175424903    0.47326777975032264 0.6554879800946404  0.8745435479485717
778.004 0.0042581749254540805   0.012611161543126458    0.4732564183343585  0.6559187977109779  0.8745557848224175
778.0042    0.003982664836275591    0.012568367677224041    0.47325248774535356 0.6563512599686995  0.874568021517651
778.0044    0.003736154949214149    0.012525573466992138    0.47325598798331603 0.6567853665335657  0.8745802580342739
778.0046    0.0035174351011359926   0.012482790801851194    0.47326691904823803 0.6572211170577422  0.8745924943722602
778.0048    0.0033247898286694277   0.012440031571027091    0.4732852809401444  0.6576585111792029  0.8746047305316111
778.005 0.003156289751263022    0.012397307663940198    0.47331107365899333 0.6580975485213417  0.8746169665123009
778.0052    0.0030116725351058225   0.012361571296781091    0.47872641909593533 0.6585382286921364  0.8746292023143241
778.0054    0.0028876468355303465   0.012327557691564073    0.4787564376650542  0.6589805512870685  0.874641437937675
778.0056    0.0027821223058328327   0.012293591459863721    0.47878563599178303 0.6594245158845404  0.8746536733823279
778.0058    0.0026936267164313515   0.012259671289292211    0.47881401407612184 0.659870122049238   0.8746659086482841
778.006 0.0026208945300527807   0.012225795867461722    0.4788415719180706  0.6603173693295149  0.8746781437355177
778.0062    0.002562869748432263    0.012191963881945987    0.4788683095176592  0.660766257259901   0.8746903786440301
778.0064    0.00251870239358941 0.01215817402043411 0.4788942268748269  0.6612167853580172  0.8747026133737952
778.0066    0.0024877422476731028   0.012124424970461433    0.4789193239896326  0.6616689531264175  0.8747148479248144
778.0068    0.0024695321419336705   0.012090715419716869    0.47894360086201926 0.662122760050603   0.8747270822970616
778.007 0.002463802182572199    0.0120570440557742  0.4789670574920159  0.6625782056020217  0.8747393164905317
778.0072    0.0024704656884992618   0.012023409566245606    0.4789896938796225  0.6630352892344882  0.8747515505052192
778.0074    0.00248961717721525 0.011989810638743263    0.479011510024839   0.6634940103851291  0.8747637843410979
778.0076    0.002521532384220501    0.011956245960879344    0.47903250592766544 0.6639543684748913  0.8747760179981696
778.0078    0.0025666699593960038   0.011922714220266027    0.4790526815881019  0.6644163629085996  0.8747882514764077
778.008 0.0026256740779573803   0.01188921410447742 0.4790720370061698  0.6648799930726939  0.8748004847758141
778.0082    0.0026993766513778933   0.011855744301201869    0.47909057218182516 0.6653452583373535  0.8748127178963625
778.0084    0.0027887970238480537   0.011822303497975447    0.47910828711511017 0.6658121580556274  0.8748249508380548
778.0086    0.0028951358690101343   0.011788890382486362    0.4791251818059845  0.6662806915616063  0.8748371836008644
778.0088    0.003019758304106799    0.011755503642308757    0.47914125625446885 0.6667508581732772  0.8748494161847862
778.009 0.003164158832147159    0.011722141965054809    0.47915651046056307 0.6672226571897616  0.8748616485898149
778.0092    0.003329897463812862    0.011688804038336694    0.4791709444242673  0.6676960878922966  0.8748738808159241
778.0094    0.0035184921924793365   0.011655488549766588    0.4791845581455814  0.6681711495440501  0.8748861128631156
778.0096    0.003731248194883138    0.011622194186956668    0.47919735162450555 0.6686478413887372  0.8748983447313631
778.0098    0.003968999694273794    0.01158891963748129 0.4792093248610527  0.6691261626530525  0.8749105764206684
778.01  0.0042317386965522235   0.011555663589028289    0.4792204778551958  0.6696061125431336  0.874922807931005
778.0102    0.004518110410783331    0.011522424729134222    0.4792308106069601  0.6700876902472391  0.8749350392623749
778.0104    0.004824775611610441    0.011489201745486838    0.47924032311632214 0.6705708949333913  0.8749472704147515
778.0106    0.0051456854971490785   0.011455993325660519    0.4792490153832941  0.6710557257511093  0.8749595013881298
778.0108    0.0054713929985587655   0.01142279815726744 0.47925688740787603 0.6715421818295213  0.8749717321825042
778.011 0.005788631880930939    0.011389614927919777    0.47926393919006793 0.6720302622781325  0.8749839627978486
778.0112    0.006080497199078833    0.011356442325229706    0.47927017072986977 0.672519966186876   0.874996193234165
778.0114    0.006327579572186692    0.011323279036809403    0.47927558202728154 0.6730112926234576  0.8750084234914267
778.0116    0.006510236213034393    0.011290123750233357    0.479280173082308   0.673504240638559   0.8750206535696352
778.0118    0.00661177027507348 0.011256975153189127    0.4792839438949388  0.6739988092585013  0.8750328834687651
778.012 0.0066217532557626664   0.011223831933251193    0.47928689446517947 0.6744949974916995  0.8750451131888101
778.0122    0.006538381977521387    0.011190692777994058    0.4792890247930321  0.6749928043240128  0.8750573427297654
778.0124    0.006368943995722512    0.011157556375105248    0.47929033487849176 0.6754922287195168  0.8750695720916049
778.0126    0.00612818913268292 0.01112442141215926 0.47929082472156137 0.6759932696220484  0.87508180127433
778.0128    0.005835258620036258    0.01109128657676827 0.4792904943222409  0.6764959259535068  0.8750940302779145
778.013 0.005510282682362526    0.011058150556544459    0.47928934368053044 0.6770001966141461  0.8751062591023601
778.0132    0.005171624068681874    0.011025012039099997    0.4792873727964299  0.6775060804795799  0.8751184877476407
778.0134    0.004834242213273702    0.010991869712009383    0.4792845816699357  0.6780135764071481  0.8751307162137577
778.0136    0.004509148142818657    0.010958722262960147    0.47928097030105415 0.6785226832288759  0.8751429445006849
778.0138    0.004203635423178391    0.01092556837952679 0.47927653868978254 0.6790333997545478  0.8751551726084174
778.014 0.003921918997679819    0.010892406749283785    0.4792712868361144  0.6795457247717588  0.8751674005369491
778.0142    0.003665894100298253    0.010859236059918705    0.4792652147400618  0.6800596570441653  0.8751796282862546
778.0144    0.003435843056448943    0.01082605499900603 0.47925832240161903 0.6805751953122933  0.875191855856335
778.0146    0.003231013824757527    0.010792862254157938    0.4792506098207863  0.681092338293065   0.8752040832471644
778.0148    0.0030500550346409198   0.010759656512986606    0.4792420769975635  0.6816110846798439  0.8752163104587442
778.015 0.0028913229012866772   0.010726436463104208    0.47923272393195065 0.6821314331414352  0.8752285374910485
778.0152    0.002753086294036009    0.010693200792085127    0.4792225506239357  0.6826533823226462  0.8752407643440785
778.0154    0.0026336566318942265   0.010659948187617108    0.47921155707354185 0.6831769308438057  0.8752529910178081
778.0156    0.002531465219036842    0.010626677337274551    0.4791997432807579  0.6837020773002805  0.8752652175122324
778.0158    0.0024451054706257705   0.010593386928631775    0.47918710924556907 0.6842288202633054  0.8752774438273457
778.016 0.0023733527120980823   0.010560075649376648    0.4791736549680041  0.6847571582781823  0.8752896699631219
778.0162    0.0023151703938851494   0.01052674218708351 0.47915938044804907 0.6852870898653729  0.8753018959195626
778.0164    0.002269708697228042    0.010493385229364537    0.47914428568570405 0.685818613518949   0.8753141216966414
778.0166    0.002236299454491045    0.010460003463831908    0.4791283706809689  0.6863517277084927  0.8753263472943604
778.0168    0.00221444989555176 0.010426595578097796    0.4791116354338437  0.6868864308756719  0.8753385727126929
778.017 0.00220383677023379 0.01039316025973635 0.4790940799443081  0.6874227214380186  0.8753507979516411
778.0172    0.0022043017494369  0.01035969619643577 0.47907570421240186 0.6879605977846857  0.8753630230111782
778.0174    0.0022158485560713585   0.010326202075770237    0.47905650823810564 0.6885000582786234  0.8753752478912991
778.0176    0.0022383806811043664   0.010291475393751196    0.47538665892415716 0.6890411012577132  0.8753874725919986
778.0178    0.0022714488613257066   0.010252079974574597    0.47536986253977176 0.6895837250293945  0.8753996971132503
778.018 0.002316519353971983    0.010212661499328781    0.4753578388376292  0.6901279278761135  0.875411921455056
778.0182    0.0023742270692276744   0.010173227604305333    0.47535058781772954 0.6906737080518426  0.8754241456173893
778.0184    0.0024453710361563904   0.010133785925795844    0.4753481094800727  0.6912210637818327  0.8754363696002523
778.0186    0.00253091084493943 0.010094344100091898    0.47535040382465876 0.6917699932648429  0.8754485934036181
778.0188    0.0026319556385643716   0.010054909763440256    0.4753574708514984  0.6923204946704445  0.8754608170274887
778.019 0.002749740159078913    0.010015490552222178    0.4753693105605755  0.6928725661390479  0.8754730404718382
778.0192    0.0028855798490205857   0.009976094102684413    0.4753859229518956  0.6934262057830435  0.8754852637366607
778.0194    0.003040793713457362    0.00993672805107381 0.4754073080254855  0.6939814116857405  0.8754974868219513
778.0196    0.003216579682382959    0.009897400033771476    0.4754334657812966  0.6945381819002884  0.8755097097276836
778.0198    0.0034138231084970484   0.009858117687024222    0.4754643962193506  0.6950965144516643  0.8755219324538592
778.02  0.0036328162929319136   0.009818888647123636    0.4755000993396475  0.6956564073327999  0.8755341550004518
778.0202    0.003872868635733575    0.009779720550361302    0.47554057514218717 0.6962178585102202  0.8755463773674634
778.0204    0.004131798584251222    0.00974062103302881 0.4755858236269698  0.6967808659150996  0.8755585995548676
778.0206    0.004405328001590956    0.009701597731417745    0.4756358447939952  0.6973454274534193  0.875570821562659
778.0208    0.004686455316810519    0.009662658281775477    0.4756906386433285  0.6979115409961467  0.8755830433908323
778.021 0.004964968289207467    0.009623810320482134    0.47575020517484506 0.6984792043860447  0.8755952650393615
778.0212    0.005227353445825379    0.009585061483740996    0.4758145443886803  0.6990484154323275  0.8756074865082479
778.0214    0.005457415736940416    0.009546419407931758    0.47588365628468804 0.6996191719149597  0.8756197077974656
778.0216    0.005637852278035556    0.009507891729301898    0.47595754086293857 0.7001914715801337  0.875631928907016
778.0218    0.00575275147434049 0.009469486084143003    0.476036198123432   0.700765312143159   0.875644149836873
778.022 0.005790542206345138    0.009431210108746658    0.47611962806616825 0.7013406912873601  0.8756563705870383
778.0222    0.005746508865878526    0.009393071439404451    0.47620783069114736 0.7019176066620951  0.8756685911574855
778.0224    0.005623934193450387    0.009355077712407971    0.4763008059983693  0.702496055884513   0.8756808115482095
778.0226    0.005433392114717419    0.00931723656400587 0.476398553987948   0.7030760365404721  0.8756930317592049
778.0228    0.005190470583287772    0.009279555630575783    0.47650107465966113 0.7036575461799364  0.8757052517904453
778.023 0.004912792115331265    0.00924204254832364 0.4766083680137418  0.7042405823213627  0.8757174716419329
778.0232    0.004617291857834896    0.00920470495362633 0.476720434049946   0.7048251424473694  0.8757296913136408
778.0234    0.0043183675365961825   0.009167550482732696    0.4768372727683931  0.7054112240085677  0.8757419108055708
778.0236    0.0040270397468805735   0.009130586771934323    0.47695888416908305 0.70599882442009    0.8757541301176972
778.0238    0.003750921342722961    0.0090938214575228  0.47708526825201586 0.7065879410630902  0.8757663492500212
778.024 0.0034946718849853675   0.009057262175789709    0.4772164250171915  0.7071785712827154  0.8757785682025163
778.0242    0.0032606474900013028   0.009020916563026641    0.47735235446461005 0.7077707123913942  0.875790786975178
778.0244    0.0030495536837373965   0.008984792255484243    0.4774930565944341  0.7083643616638455  0.8758030055680002
778.0246    0.002861003677103549    0.008948896889536243    0.47763853140634377 0.7089595163391746  0.875815223980957
778.0248    0.002693950793456194    0.008913238101392633    0.4777887789006698  0.709556173623304   0.8758274422140504
778.025 0.0025470005075755513   0.008877823527426082    0.4779437990770706  0.710154330683048   0.8758396602672536
778.0252    0.002418623010612312    0.008842660803887504    0.4781035919357142  0.710753984650321   0.8758518781405685
778.0254    0.00230729046527594 0.008807757567068485    0.47826815747660073 0.7113551326203872  0.875864095833969
778.0256    0.002211560601559665    0.008773121453260611    0.4784374956997301  0.7119577716509919  0.8758763133474565
778.0258    0.0021301238818424544   0.00873876009875547 0.47861160660510227 0.7125618987626953  0.8758885306810049
778.026 0.002061827011720025    0.008704681139844649    0.47879049019271736 0.7131675109395176  0.875900747834609
778.0262    0.0020056818283013967   0.008670892212781486    0.4789741464627868  0.7137746051265548  0.8759129648082633
778.0264    0.0019608657272253273   0.008637400953934404    0.479162575414893   0.7143831782327473  0.8759251816019415
778.0266    0.0019267177174483565   0.008604214999518859    0.4793557770494644  0.7149932271263545  0.8759373982156455
778.0268    0.0019027327395418894   0.008571341985901898    0.47955375136606176 0.7156047486383349  0.8759496146493492
778.027 0.0018885558992395924   0.00853878954933721 0.4797564983649019  0.7162177395617871  0.8759618309030539
778.0272    0.0018839776037689058   0.008506565326116374    0.479964018045985   0.7168321966489184  0.8759740469767333
778.0274    0.001888930136676138    0.008474676952530983    0.48017631040931086 0.7174481166138414  0.8759862628703826
778.0276    0.0019034858835387297   0.008443132064872622    0.48039337545487965 0.7180654961307722  0.8759984785839963
778.0278    0.0019278571573759725   0.008411938299432877    0.48061521318269124 0.7186843318343752  0.8760106941175477
778.028 0.00196239731009442 0.008381103292468486    0.48084182359300603 0.7193046203182534  0.8760229094710391
778.0282    0.0020076024992791318   0.008350634680341154    0.4810732066853088  0.7199263581368471  0.8760351246444437
778.0284    0.00206411304103196 0.008320540099273207    0.4813093624601256  0.7205495418029906  0.8760473396377637
778.0286    0.0021327126442329345   0.00829082718562467 0.4815502909169195  0.7211741677898194  0.8760595544509725
778.0288    0.0022143228891518046   0.008261503575652699    0.4817959920559562  0.7218002325264333  0.876071769084072
778.029 0.0023099889633567475   0.00823257690564888 0.4820464658772358  0.7224277324032525  0.876083983537036
778.0292    0.0024208507644136166   0.008204054811904804    0.48230171238075825 0.7230566637683075  0.8760961978098585
778.0294    0.002548090911354231    0.008175944930712054    0.48256173156652354 0.7236870229272752  0.8761084119025353
778.0296    0.002692847956048065    0.008148254898362215    0.4828265234345317  0.7243188061425659  0.8761206258150394
778.0298    0.00285607941574531 0.00812099235111613 0.4830960879850919  0.7249520096358968  0.8761328395473729
778.03  0.003038356016742095    0.008094164925327378    0.4833704252175912  0.7255866295851723  0.876145053099509
778.0302    0.003238986813810955    0.008066333565668004    0.4822708438215909  0.7262226621248379  0.8761572664714499
778.0304    0.003456957328000581    0.008038195029378144    0.4825571334638987  0.726860103346558   0.8761694796631692
778.0306    0.0036897816855907535   0.00801052006526775 0.48285030904606974 0.7274989492973469  0.8761816926746684
778.0308    0.003932569313395786    0.007983319690840603    0.48315037056810384 0.7281391959815268  0.8761939055059216
778.031 0.00417780678674605 0.007956604923600476    0.4834573180300011  0.7287808393578935  0.8762061181569231
778.0312    0.004415087696132333    0.007930386781051154    0.48377115143176147 0.7294238753429709  0.8762183306276679
778.0314    0.004631334674413692    0.007904676280696408    0.484091870773385   0.7300682998036514  0.8762305429181297
778.0316    0.00481177155526518 0.007879484440011682    0.48441947605524804 0.7307141085685196  0.8762427550283103
778.0318    0.004941750596828371    0.007854822276558041    0.48475396727660575 0.7313612974149974  0.8762549669581832
778.032 0.005009207266150079    0.007830700807783215    0.48509534443821856 0.7320098620781054  0.8762671787077501
778.0322    0.005007113916898944    0.007807131051245839    0.4854436075393103  0.7326597982453329  0.8762793902769849
778.0324    0.004935088677290728    0.00778412402442196 0.4857987565802653  0.7333111015599338  0.876291601665889
778.0326    0.004799517951401925    0.007761690744815355    0.4861607915610833  0.7339637676154359  0.8763038128744364
778.0328    0.004612134639624371    0.007739842229929803    0.4865297124817645  0.7346177919618831  0.8763160239026221
778.033 0.004387616735934635    0.0077185894972690815   0.4869055193423089  0.7352731701013225  0.8763282347504403
778.0332    0.004141054970472729    0.007697943564336969    0.4872882121427164  0.735929897487185   0.8763404454178647
778.0334    0.0038859829477153602   0.00767791544861483 0.4876777908834339  0.7365879695266334  0.8763526559048975
778.0336    0.003633268396823615    0.007658516167651992    0.4880742555635755  0.7372473815786444  0.876364866211512
778.0338    0.0033908012281063504   0.007639756738908152    0.48847760618404273 0.73790812895439    0.8763770763377101
778.034 0.003163726480682661    0.007621648179929751    0.48888784274391844 0.7385702069159656  0.8763892862834655
778.0342    0.002954949251529448    0.007604201508198876    0.48930496524365735 0.7392336106771036  0.8764014960487798
778.0344    0.0027657067767220384   0.007587427741219305    0.48972897368325935 0.7398983354028984  0.8764137056336269
778.0346    0.002596089519929695    0.007571337896494816    0.49015986806272455 0.7405643762075288  0.8764259150380014
778.0348    0.00244546194167148 0.007555942991529187    0.4905976483820529  0.7412317281593143  0.8764381242618982
778.035 0.00231277589416452 0.007541254043826197    0.4910423146412443  0.7419003862727664  0.8764503333052908
778.0352    0.002196790073613731    0.007527282070874151    0.4914938668408162  0.7425703455139803  0.8764625421681806
778.0354    0.00209621571201152 0.007514038090208607    0.4919523049797418  0.743241600799699   0.8764747508505422
778.0356    0.0020098082951899086   0.007501533119303257    0.49241762905906344 0.7439141469940145  0.8764869593523765
778.0358    0.001936421813692953    0.0074897781756903216   0.4928898390777231  0.7445879789121224  0.8764991676736577
778.036 0.001875038164792204    0.007478784276858942    0.49336893503624596 0.7452630913160048  0.8765113758143802
778.0362    0.0018247808216455528   0.007468562440312894    0.49385491693463196 0.7459394789171857  0.8765235837745391
778.0364    0.001784919100669047    0.007459123683555959    0.4943477847728811  0.7466171363764647  0.8765357915541079
778.0366    0.0017548672970953032   0.007450479024091914    0.49484753855099334 0.7472960583009278  0.8765479991530881
778.0368    0.0017341814908847456   0.0074426394794245366   0.49535417826896877 0.7479762392460437  0.8765602065714536
778.037 0.0017225558223969073   0.0074356160670500885   0.4958677039273951  0.7486576737150528  0.8765724138092063
```

Comment: A workaround I found was to add a `set rmargin screen 0.6` line and
set explicitly the key sample and text width and spacing like `set k samplen 50 spacing 1.25 w 500 a columnheader rm c Left rev`